# Scheduling Azure container instances on demand

Tags: azure, containers, azure-container-instances, nomad

I have tasks running on VM and the following sequence of events. For scaling purposes I need to be able to run operations on demand and possibly in parallel.
A simple sequence of events
1. Execute task
2. Task create dataset file.
3. Startup container instance (Linux)
4. In container Execute operations on data set
5. Write updated dataset
6. Vm consume dataset
Environment is Azure.
Azure files for exchanging dataset. (2,5)
PowerShell for creating and starting container.
PowerShell could be used for sequence 4

I do not wish to use platform specific event handlers as it may be necessary to port to other runtime environments. This is a simple use case which I guess many has touched on before. Anyone have any idea if HashiCorp Nomad could bring value? Any tips for other tooling which can bring added value?

Comment: .net core and rabbitmq may be used to exchange messages. For instance server to send data on which file the container should process.

Comment: what is a `task`? assuming you initiate it, make your task spin up container instances. i dont see any problem

Comment: Try [Jenkins with ACI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-jenkins).